# Django all-auth allow users to login only if the user email address is verified

Tags: django, django-allauth, email-verification, loginview

How do i override AllAuth default LoginView to allow users to login only if their email address is verified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Aullauth configuration docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

You need to set: `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION="mandatory"`

> When set to “mandatory” the user is blocked from logging in until the email address is verified. Choose “optional” or “none” to allow logins with an unverified e-mail address. In case of “optional”, the e-mail verification mail is still sent, whereas in case of “none” no e-mail verification mails are sent.

Also keep in mind before setting it you need to also set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True`

> Setting this to “mandatory” requires ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED to be True

Comment: Thank you so much mate. I tried it before but it gave me assert error i might have done something wrong but it works fine now.. thanks again

Comment: Also, how i add custom messages to allauth default views ?